# Shisha Ushloshim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred thirty-six?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Teshuva Tefila U'Tzedaka = Tzom Kol Momon / Tzom = 136 / Kol = 136 / Momon = 136

In Parshas Vayeitzei by the dream, the Baal Haturim says that Sulam = 136 / Oini = 136 / Momon = 136 to tell us that money comes and money goes

Comment: Checkmark for Gematria from the Baal Haturim.

Comment: My Rabbi mentioned this gematria in his derasha this past Shabbat, prompting me to come here and make sure it was registered. I'm glad to see that it was, and that I already duly appreciated it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Chapter 136 in Tehilim is the last Tehilim said before Baruch She'amar on Shabbat (Nusach Sefarad)